# Pairing elements of to same length arrays, and returning true if at least one element of each pair is >= 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to pair elements of an array with the data of the other array in the same order and only once.

```
const num1 = [5, 10, 0, 1000, 6, 5]
const num2 = [6, 11, 0, -1000, 4, 5]
```

to be able to then loop through the arrays in a way that checks if

```
[5, 6] [10, 11] [0, 0] [1000, -1000] [6, 4] [5, 5]
```

this way

if num1 >= 5 || num2 >= 5 then console.log(true) if not console.log(false)

so far I have this

```
const num1 = [5, 10, 0, 1000, 6, 5]
const num2 = [6, 11, 0, -1000, 4, 5]
for (i = 0; i < num1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < num2.length; j++) {
    if ((num1[i] >= 5) && (num2[j] >= 5)) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
}
```

but it gives 12 results in the console instead of the expected 6
true
false
true
true
false
true

thank you for your time.

Comment: Actually, I'd expect your code to print 36 outputs and not 12. You don't need the inner loop. As the input array do have same length, you can just use the index of the first loop to access both array. furhtermore you should only output your result *after* you checked all of the array and not in every iteration ...

Comment: Thank your so much for your time, I just got what the number in front of my results in the console meant, and it did give me 36 results!

Comment: Do you mean `||` as in the description or `&&` as in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
const num1 = [5, 10, 0, 1000, 6, 5]
const num2 = [6, 11, 0, -1000, 4, 5]

for (i = 0; i < num1.length; i++) {
    if (num1[i] >= 5 && num2[i] >= 5) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I had gone with that but misunderstood the console.log return!
I can breath now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and make it code succinct as:

```js
const num1 = [5, 10, 0, 1000, 6, 5]
const num2 = [6, 11, 0, -1000, 4, 5]

num1.forEach((num, index) => console.log(num >= 5 && num2[index] >= 5))
```

Comment: Even shorter, love it. Thank you, I was curious as to wether or not I could use forEach but I'm not familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you were performing a nested loop which means you were comparing each element. I have used a single loop to loop through both lists simultaneously.

```js
const num1 = [5, 10, 0, 1000, 6, 5]
const num2 = [6, 11, 0, -1000, 4, 5]
for (i = 0; i < num1.length; i++) {
    if ((num1[i] >= 5) || (num2[i] >= 5)) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code you were performing a nested loop which means you were comparing each element. I have used a single loop to loop through both lists simultaneously.